# NGINX not following alias directive

Tags: nginx

I am trying to get nginx to server some static files.  I put in what I believe should be the proper directive to alias the url, but nginx is refusing to server the page.  My server.conf is as follows:

```
server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Make site accessible from server.fqdn.suffix
        server_name server.fqdn.suffix;

        location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/poindexter/inspire/static/;
        }

        # Include the basic h5bp config set
        include /etc/nginx/h5bp/basic.conf;
}
```

I assumed that this would redirect to the `/usr/share/nginx/html/poindexter/inspire/static/` directory.  And for the autoindex it seems to work.  But when you click on a file it generates a 404 error.  I took an strace and sure enough, it is not honoring the alias.

```
[pid  2542] <... epoll_wait resumed> {{EPOLLIN, {u32=1822502928, u64=139901792235536}}}, 512, 4294967295) = 1
[pid  2542] accept4(10, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(37845), sin_addr=inet_addr("198.55.232.86")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 24
[pid  2542] epoll_ctl(21, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 24, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLET, {u32=1822503697, u64=139901792236305}}) = 0
[pid  2542] epoll_wait(21, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=1822503697, u64=139901792236305}}}, 512, 10000) = 1
[pid  2542] recvfrom(24, "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.cs"..., 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) = 772
[pid  2542] open("/usr/share/nginx/html/static/css/bootstrap.min.css", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2542] write(8, "2014/03/05 21:59:23 [error] 2542"..., 328) = 328
[pid  2542] writev(24, [{"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nServer: "..., 172}, {"<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Fou"..., 116}, {"<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</bo"..., 46}], 3) = 334
[pid  2542] setsockopt(24, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
[pid  2542] recvfrom(24, 0x14e9240, 1024, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I would really appreciate any help I could get.  I am very stuck.

Comment: What is inside `basic.conf`?

Comment: It was created during the install and I have not removed it.  It is a pointer to # Basic h5bp rules

include h5bp/directive-only/x-ua-compatible.conf;
include h5bp/location/expires.conf;
include h5bp/location/cross-domain-fonts.conf;
include h5bp/location/protect-system-files.conf;

Comment: It's still a list of includes. I'm sure there is some rule about css files inside of these includes.

Comment: You are correct.  I emailed the other programmer on the project and it appears it was from html5 boilerplate.  There was a rule about js/css in there. location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}  I ma not sure which of these is killing js/css.  Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several way to fix this.

#### 1

Just add symlink from `/usr/share/nginx/html/static/` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/poindexter/inspire/static/` and remove `alias` directive. It something like aliasing on file system level.

```
location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
}
```

#### 2

Remove `location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {` block.

#### 3

Use rewrite (this solution make use the fact you static directory in inside your root)

```
location ^~ /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /poindexter/inspire$1;
}
```